# Remove value from column by row in SQlite

Tags: database, sqlite

How to delete a value 'For you'(message_to) from a table clients where Login = Mike using SQlite?

```
table clients

Login | message_to | sender
---------------------------
David | Hello      | Kevin
Mike  | For you    | Sea
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update clients
set message_to=null
where login='Mike'
```